# Is [a vocative][1] used as a subject in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, vocative

Is [a vocative](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/what-is-the-vocative-in-english) used as a subject in a sentence? If not, what is it used for? (By the way, what is the linguistic term that corresponds to the classification of the components in a sentence into subject, object, ...?)

Comment: Is "[grammatical relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_relation)" the term you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no - because what follows the vocative is usually either an *imperative*, which has no subject, or addresses the audience using a pronoun, which then becomes the subject.

**Example 1:**

> David! Come here!

The vocative attracts the attention of the audience, and then the imperative addresses them directly without the use of a subject.

**Example 2:**

> David! You must come here!

The statement uses the pronoun 'you' as the subject.

From a more practical point of view - the whole point of the evocative is to indicate the 'missing' subject so that the right person or group will understand the command or request.

Comment: what is it used as, if not subject?

Comment: It's called the vocative because it is a function in its own right. It is used to avoid any confusion when using the imperative, or when addressing a person directly because we don't use a person's name in the third person when speaking directly to them. For example, if I said "*Tim should look up 'vocative' in the dictionary*", you would think I was talking **to** somebody else **about** you. So what I'd say is "*Tim! You should look up 'vocative' in the dictionary*".